# Sniff Multicast IPV6 UDP Datagrams using Python, need to send?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ipv6, multicast

I wrote a piece of code largely inspired by [mcast.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo/sockets/mcast.py) to sniff UDP datagrams on ipv6. However, something weird happens.

I can only see packets on the network if i first start the `send()` method
(i.e `file.py -s` in one window, and `file.py` in another), this allows me to see other UDP packets on the specified port. But if I dont start `file.py -s` , nd I only run `file.py`, No packets are sniffed. What gives?

Specifically, it seems that the call to `sendto(...)` is what makes the `receive()` be able to sniff. Is there a solution to this? I only intend to listen to specific UDP IPV6 packets, not really send. Is it because I need to send a join message to the IPV6 multicast group first, or? (I cant see any such packets in wireshark..)

```
import sys
import socket
import time
import struct
import win_inet_pton #https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_inet_pton

SOURCE_PORT = 16000
DEST_PORT = 26000
MULTICAST_ADDR = 'ff02::1' #IPV6 Multicast Address
socket.IPPROTO_IPV6 = 41 #Workaround for missing constants on Win32 systems.

def send(): #Send packets

    MY_IP6 = "fe80::8d96:ab99:7447:1c5c%11" #Link local IPV6 address..
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS, 1)
    sock.bind((MY_IP6, SOURCE_PORT))

    while True:
        sock.sendto("foo", (MULTICAST_ADDR, DEST_PORT)) 
        #Needed to be able to receive packets..?
        time.sleep(0.2)

def receive(): #Receive packets

    addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(MULTICAST_ADDR, None)[0]
    sock = socket.socket(addrinfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('', DEST_PORT))

    #Join Multicast grp.
    group = socket.inet_pton(addrinfo[0], addrinfo[4][0])
    mreq = group + struct.pack('@I', 0) # Magic?
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, mreq)

    while True:
        d , s = sock.recvfrom(4000)
        print str(s) + "  " + repr(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        if sys.argv[1] == "-s":
            send()
    else:
        receive()
```

Comment: `Sniff` is hardware level, install wireshark and check which header or content are missing.  You see more packet on wireshark like this :  target mac `333300010003`  meaning IPv6 multi-casting (`LLMNR` mean `86dd` ) . Basically warning `Don't run more script on same idle !` Like: server on `cmd/terminal` (`c:\pythonXX\python.exe my_awesome.py`) and client on idle `F5` start. Add your traceback in question.

Comment: @dsgdfg I dont follow.. I dont get a traceback, did you read my question?
I am using `eth.addr == 33:33:00:00:00:01` in wireshark if that's what you mean.. I run one instance of the script

Comment: To clarify: I'm not /sending/ malformed packets or anything, I want to read perfectly fine packets. This does not work unless I call `sendto` on a socket before calling `receive`.

Comment: Who talking first ? `Accept a connection` not equal to `receive` or `send`. So your client waiting a data for sending your answer. Change client side to `constantly send data`. You got a script about of `hardware buffer management` ? if not, use `Send and receive`.

Comment: UDP is connectionless, Im not establishing a connection between a host and receiver.